# How can I configure vhost express to work with three application folders

Tags: express, express-vhost

I have three folders on a Debian server with three application node (express + ejs + view).
Each application is a www site on port 3000. It is clear that this cannot work at the same time. Each individual application - www site works great. I also have an nginx reverse proxy configured that proxies ssl requests (443) to express:3000.
I ask for help on how to configure vhost to work with applications in folders. They should all run on port 3000 with its own static and views folders.

> Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory
> "/var/express/vhost/ejs"
> at Function.render (/var/express/uc.domain.com/dev/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:597:17)
> at ServerResponse.render (/var/express/uc.domain.com/dev/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1039:7)
> at file:///var/express/uc.domain.com/dev/express.js:25:7
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/express/uc.domain.com/dev/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
> at next (/var/express/uc.domain.com/dev/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
> at Route.dispatch (/var/express/uc.domain.com/dev/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/express/uc.domain.com/dev/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
> at /var/express/uc.domain.com/dev/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
> at Function.process_params (/var/express/uc.domain.com/dev/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
> at next (/var/express/uc.domain.com/dev/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)

it is vhost.js

```
import express from 'express'
import vhost from 'vhost'
import https from 'https'
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

import app from '../uc.domain.com/dev/express.js'

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/var/express/_ssl/helios.uc.domain.com.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/var/express/_ssl/helios.uc.domain.com.crt'),
  requestCert: false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const app = express()

tools.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('This is the tools.uc.domain.com')
})


app.use(vhost('dev.uc.domain.com', app))
app.use(vhost('tools.uc.domain.com', tools))

const server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`- https://dev.uc.domain.com:${port},`)
  console.log(`- https://tools.uc.domain.com:${port}`) 
  console.log('For end of work press Ctrl+C')
})
```

application-site.js in folder '../uc.domain.com/dev/express.js'

```
import express from 'express'
import https from 'https'
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import router from './system/routes.js'

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/var/express/_ssl/helios.uc.domain.com.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/var/express/_ssl/helios.uc.domain.com.crt'),
  requestCert: false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const app = express()
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'ejs'))

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'static')))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(router)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Sweet home Alabama',
  })
})

app.get('/:sub', (req, res) => {
  res.render(req.params.sub, {
    title: 'Sweet home Alabama',
  })
})

// const server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, () => {
//  console.log(`- https://dev.uc.domain.com:${port})
// })

export default app
```

Comment: Why dont you let NGINX do the reverse proxing and SSL termination? Kick out the HTTPS part in your node apps, move that into nginx, and start each node app on a different port like 3001, 3002, 3003. No need for SSL/TLS for localhost/loopback/same host communications.

Comment: @Marc You may be right about SSL, but as I wrote earlier, my applications are complete www sites, and edit this not important to me right now. Your proposal to run applications on different ports and manage them on nginx is acceptable and I have seen it, but I would like to make all applications on one port, if possible)

Comment: You cannot run multiple http(s) servers on a single port. What you can do is  something similar with a Layer 7 application proxy. Thats exactly what nginx does. It check the request host header and forwards that request to the app. E.g. foo.example.com:80 -> 127.0.0.1:3001, bar.example.com:80 -> 127.0.0.1:3002. Both domains can be accessed via port 80, but the underlaying application behind runs on a different port. If i understand you approach correctly, you already try to solve/do exactly this via node. Dont re-invent the wheel, use nginx for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as @Marc suggested, nginx as a reverse proxy. The more I work in this configuration, the more I like it and now I can manage my applications via pm2. Not sure if this would be possible with vhost

nginx config: /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name tools.uc.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /var/express/_ssl/helios.uc.domain.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/express/_ssl/helios.uc.domain.com.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:3008;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name srv.uc.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /var/express/_ssl/helios.uc.domain.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/express/_ssl/helios.uc.domain.com.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:3009;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```